# Mapping Variable Entity types in M:N relationship via EntityName table

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, data-modeling, entity-relationship

I often see "linking" tables for M:N relationship, where N can be 1..X types of entities/classes, so that the table contains classNameId referring to ClassName table and classPK referring to the particular Entity table.

How is this called ? Does it have an alternative with the same effect without having the EntityName table ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the ER model, entities and subentities can be related by inheritance, the same way classes and subclasses are in an object model.  The problem comes up when you transform your ER model into a relational model.  The relational model does not support inheritance as such.

The design pattern is called  is called generalization-specialization or gen-spec for short.  Unfortunately, many database tutorials skip over how to design tables for a gen-spec situation.

But it's well understood.It looks quite different from your model,  but you could create views that make it look like your model  if necessary.  Look up "generalization specialization relational modeling" for explanations of how to do this.

The main trick is that the specialized tables "inherit" the value of their primary key from the PK of the generalized table.  The meaning of "inherit" here is that it's a copy of the same value.  Thus the PK in each specialized table is also an FK link back to the correpsonding entry in the generalized table.

Comment: There is no generalization / inheritance involved here... Quite frankly, it's a long time since I saw such a chaotic answer ;-)